# Regex expressions for C++ methods and classes

Tags: c++, regex

What are the regex expressions for reliably finding C++ methods and classes?

Comment: If it only were so simple...

Comment: The answer to your next question will be...ANTLR 2.7 (old I know) and the C++ grammar for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no regular expressions to reliably find C++ methods and classes. You need a real parser.

Comment: In most if not all cases a parser with symbol table support to properly identify templates.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions really are not suited to parsing languages like C++. Features of the language like templates require additional knowledge to parse properly.

Consider the following

```
template<class T> T SomeTemplate();
typedef int SomeType;

if(SomeTemplate<SomeType>())
{
}
```

How do you distinguish between a comparison and calling a template function?